# Seagate NTFS "image not recognized"

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ntfs

Recently bought a seagate backup plus HDD, and cannot write via MBP. I can see it in disk utility and USB device tree. Under disk utility I can successfully use first aid but still cannot copy files to disk.

I have downloaded the paragon driver, but always shows not recognized, as attached.
[image]

Any solutions?

I am using El Capitan, 10.11.6

Comment: Either clear your browser cache [or less disruptively, use another browser] & try the download again. Once a DL is cached badly, your browser is likely to DL the same bad copy every time.

Comment: If your computer hasn’t been rebooted in a while, force quit Finder and try again.